# Convert processing sketch into executable

Tags: java, jar, export, processing, exe

I am using processing, and cannot figure out how to turn my processing sketch into an .exe file. So far nothing has worked.

I have a lot of images in different folders within my processing sketch, and I cannot seem to figure out the steps I need to take to end up with an executable and a folder which it is in (the type you might download from the internet)

Comment: file > export application ?

Comment: Right, but this 1) does not create a .exe and 2) does not run when I click it

Comment: What version of Processing editor are you using?

Answer (score 7):

You can do this two ways:

From your Processing editor, by clicking the "Export button", then you have the options of creating an "Embed Java" or a "Full Screen (Present mode)". Bought of this options create a folder containing the .exe file.

[image: Exporting in Processing]

this creates a new folder inside your sketch folder.

[image: Your sketch folder]

here you can find the executable file.

[image: The executable file]

The other way would be by having your project mix with java in some other IDE like Eclipse or Intelij. Follow this tutorial on how to do that http://www.learningprocessing.com/tutorials/processing-in-eclipse/
then you can export your work like any java aplication, if you decide to work with eclipse here it's how to do so http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftjexpapp.html

Hope this could be helpful.
Regards
Jose

Comment: except neither of these files cointain a .exe and it gives me a null pointer exeption

Comment: Thank you for the images. I think was clicking on the .jar file *FACEPALM* so sorru

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+E for newer versions.